# Do cards that say "creatures you control" trigger Heroic?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have a creature or multiple creatures that have a heroic ability and I activate a sorcery or instant that has an effect to "creatures you control" will this trigger the heroic ability?

Comment: Targeting requires the word "target". Note that some keyword abilities represent abilities that use the word "target", and note that Auras target what they will enchant when they're on the stack because the word "target" is used in the rules for casting Auras.

Comment: @ikegami I suspected as much, although another related question arises, what about an overloaded spell? As a normal spell it obviously would trigger since it says target. If I'm understanding this correctly given though since definition of overload removes the word target from the card it would not trigger anymore.

Comment: That's exactly right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, those effects do not ***target*** a creature. The sorcery or instant card must specifically say that it ***targets*** a creature to trigger Heroic effects. Enchantment Aura cards also target a creature, although they may not say so explicitly on the card.

Comment: Ah yes, I suspected as much. My roommate got all angry with me for being "overly technical" but I think he's just upset I blew his deck strategy apart.

Comment: This is exactly what makes Cyclonic Rift a staple card for RTR/Theros standard's blue devotion decks. Hexproof and protection care about targeting. Cyclonic Rift doesn't target. It just gets rid of everything. *Everything.* (except lands)

Comment: @JonathanHobbs Cyclonic Rift doesn't target only when it is **overloaded**, just to be clear

Comment: @bengoesboom Right, yes. :) Good correction!

Comment: Clarification: Enchantment Aura _spells_ target a creature; Enchantment Aura _permanents_ do not.

Comment: @Fr33dan "Overly technical" is basically the only way to interpret Magic cards in a consistent manner.