# "Each" and Targeting

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I played with a group recently who was convinced that an effect like "each creature" will target (while "all creatures" does not).

I consider rule 114.9a good enough to prove that it must say "target" or have a keyword whose rule says target or... it doesn't target.

But they are so sure that I think I will get some push back.  Is there anything besides rule 114.9a that I could use to clearly show that "each" does not target?  (Assuming I am right and it doesn't.)

Comment: Very similar to this question: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/14777/do-cards-that-say-creatures-you-control-trigger-heroic

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To quote 114.9a, with bold for emphasis:

> 114.9a Just because an object or player is being affected by a spell or ability doesn't make that object or player a target of that spell or ability. **Unless that object or player is identified by the word "target"** in the text of that spell or ability, or the rule for that keyword ability, **it's not a target**.

That really seems as straight-forward as possible. Does the spell or keyword rule use the exact specific word "target"? No? Then "it's not a target". The only other thing I can think of that may help is to show them gatherer rulings from any number of cards. Look at any card with Overload, for example: [Cyclonic Rift](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cyclonic%20Rift), [Blustersquall](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Blustersquall), etc. Both of these have Gatherer rulings that specifically state "If you pay the overload cost, the spell won't have any targets."

Comment: The overload card rulings will work perfectly!

Comment: More importantly, they have the follow-up ruling under it which says "Because a spell with overload doesn't target when its overload cost is paid, it may affect permanents with hexproof or with protection from the appropriate color."

Comment: Re "Does the spell or keyword rule use the exact specific word 'target'?" That leaves out Auras. They target when they're on the stack.

Comment: @corsiKa, I don't rely on rulings; they're sometimes outdated. But it wouldn't have hurt to mention it too.

Comment: @ikegami Isn't that covered by the special exception 114.1b?

Comment: @corsiKa, Yes, "114.1b Aura spells are always targeted. [...]"